# Function to Identify errors when formatting varchar(month, day, year) to single date in SQL (Varchar out of range)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have the following table, and I need to format the date details into a single date.

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
| Date Type  | Month (Varchar) | Day(Varchar) | Year (Varchar) |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
| Invalid    |              02 |           31 |           2022 |
| Invalid    |              04 |           31 |           2021 |
| Invalid    |              02 |           29 |           2022 |
| Good Date  |              03 |           22 |           2022 |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I use a case statement to filter out erroneous dates.

first

```
,Case when ( (s.[Day]='31' and s.[Month]='02') 
Or (s.[Day]='30' and s.[Month]='02') or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2016') 
 or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2019') 
 or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2021') 
 or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2022') 
 or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2023') 
or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2025') 
 or (s.[Day]='29' and s.[Month]='02' and s.[year]='2026') 
 Or (s.[Day]='31' and s.[Month]='06')  Or (s.[Day]='31' and s.[Month]='04')
 Or (s.[Day]='31' and s.[Month]='09')   Or (s.[Day]='31' and s.[Month]='11') OR (s.[Day] IS null Or s.[Month] IS null Or s.[Year] IS null ) )
   
   then 1 else 0 end as [Wrong Date Entry]
```

Second

```
CASE when [Wrong Date Entry]=0 
THEN CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST([day]AS VARCHAR(2))) 
ELSE NULL END AS [Date Type single date]
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this?
Is there an error function I can use to identify any errors in the table and rule them out before formatting the dates(in MS SQL 2016)?

Thanks !

Comment: I guess you can have a look on TRY_CAST-function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: *"Is there a more efficient way to write this"* Why not fix your design and use a `date` data type to store the data in the first place? Then you *can't* have bad dates because you *can't* store a value of `2022-02-31` in a `date` value.

Comment: If you *must* store the data in a bad data type (`varchar` for the month *number* is a **terrible** choice of data type) then have a look at `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: I don't disagree. I only have read access to the Db . I can recommend the vendor to fix the design.

Comment: Thanks so much @sergey, these functions are helpful!

Comment: February has only 28 days and April only 30.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT([Year], [Month], [Day]), 112)` suffices.